# Forward ports to the same computer even when the IP changes due to DHCP with D-link wireless router

Tags: router, wireless-networking, dhcp

I have a PC connected directly to a wireless router D-LINK WBR-1310, and I use port forwarding to that PC so I can connect to it via SSH remotely.

However, I use the built in DHCP to manage IP addresses as devices are added and removed to the network, and when the computer is restarted it usually gets a different IP.

Is there a way with this router to assign a fixed address to the PC attached via a cable rather than wireslessly? Or to a PC by mac address or other identifier?

Alternatively how do I set up the network without DHCP to manage the IP addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DHCP for computers you don't access and assign static IP's to each computer you do.  Try `Start -> Run -> ncpa.cpl -> right-click LAN adapter -> Properties -> Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) -> Properties` for Windows XP.

Unfortunately (and strangely) this router does not support DHCP assignments by MAC (or any other identifier).  Even more odd is that some folks have found you can [flash it with particular D-link DI-524 firmware revisions](http://www.rage3d.com/board/showthread.php?t=33922502) and gain DHCP assignment functionality:

> After loading DI-524 firmware into my WBR-1310, I set up the router to my preferences, and it works like this for over 2 weeks, without any problems on any of the machines.

Comment: Actually I'm using linux for the ssh server, but the same thing should work. Interesting that the firmware from a different router works, but sounds a bit too experimental for me :)